# how to hide css content from overflowing

Tags: html, css

how will i hide css content from overflowing..I want to display price tag in that css element but it is coming out of my card.

```css
.content{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 309px;
    top: 206px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    //overflow: hidden;
    //display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 l4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/400" style="height: 300px;width: 418px;">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: use `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: How is this PHP related?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful, what you are saying is an element is breaking the box model, correct.  ( ie. it's sticking outside the confines of a parent element)

Comment: `//overflow: hidden`, `//` is not a comment in CSS (or in HTML, for that matter). This is just a syntax error.

Comment: @JeremyThille - good catch, I would add a CSS comment is `/*   */` like a block comment.

Comment: Use `/* My comment */` in css to comment something out. Use `<!-- My comment -->` in html to comment something out. Use `// My comment` in php to comment something.

Comment: lol i know that i added that comment line just to show that i tried using that but it did not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 l4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden;height: 300px;width: 418px;">
        <img src="assets/img/jonatan-pie-415847.jpg" style="height: 300px;width: 418px;">
        <div style="content:'';
                  position: absolute;
                  left: 309px;
                  top: 206px;
                  z-index: 1;
                  border-radius: 100%;
                  width: 160px;
                  height: 160px;
                  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Not sure if this is what you want. One important thing is to have `card-image` positioned relative, then you can use that as a reference point instead of the window.  Then this has to have the overflow applied to it to hide the content, as it's the container the content is in.

Your image is broken for me and it's not clear exactly what or where you want it.

It would probably be better to use the card-image with a background image and then add the circle as normal content inside of it.

```css
.card-image{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 300px;
    width: 418px; 
}

.price-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 309px;
    top: 206px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    padding: 50px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 l4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image" style="background-image: url('assets/img/jonatan-pie-415847.jpg')" >
            <div class="price-wrapper" >
                      $9.99
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This will give you a bit more control over the content inside of the circle.  I left the background image as an inline style, this way you can change it with like PHP code or what have you.

I threw a bit of "flair" in to it so I could put an actual price value you in there, not sure if you need that, but I added `box-sizing` and `color` for it.

Just a thought.

Comment: Which part, the second one?  call it academic curiosity.

Comment: yes ! but i want it to be responsive...and the image should fit into card size

Comment: is to possible to do that without using background image ??? because i already have a card ready i just want a code for that price and black background with opacity

Comment: with `background-size: cover;`  means `cover:Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges`  see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: You can also use `contain` which is `Resize the background image to make sure the image is fully visible` but it wont stretch the image.  By leafing it as a inline style you can do `<div class="card-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $card_img; ?>')">`

Comment: Actually the scene is.. i already have a page ready i just want to put that price part in that page in all my cards...so i will  have to do aloot of changes if i use this...

Comment: and that page was not made by me there are 4-5 people working on same project :D

Comment: well if you have to put text in that circle, it's going to be extremely difficult.  Things work better if you use them how they are supposed to be used, if it's a background image, then it's a background image.

Comment: hey i tried it with your code...it worked ! but now how will i make it responsive???any suggestion..

Answer (score 2):

The overflowing div has a `position:absolute`. So you have to set its direct parent (`.card-image`) a `position:relative` so it "catches" the absolutely positioned div as a child.

Then apply `overflow: hidden` to the container.

```css
.card-image {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 418px;
   height : 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 l4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="assets/img/jonatan-pie-415847.jpg" style="height: 300px;width: 418px;">
        <div style="content:'';
                  position: absolute;
                  left: 309px;
                  top: 206px;
                  z-index: 1;
                  border-radius: 100%;
                  width: 160px;
                  height: 160px;
                  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is the right answer, just wanted to say that :)

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. It feels like I'm complimenting myself :)

Comment: Thank you jeremy.. will surely contact you for more doubts :D @JeremyThille

Comment: Well that's another question altogether. If my answer to this question is satisfying, please consider validating and upvoting it.

Comment: ...then please consider validating and upvoting it. Like, manually validating and upvoting it.

Comment: actually i dont know how to do that...lol ! this is my first post in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 l4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="assets/img/jonatan-pie-415847.jpg" style="height: 300px;width: 418px;">
        <div style="content:'';
                  position: absolute;
                  left: 309px;
                  top: 206px;
                  z-index: 1;
                  border-radius: 100%;
                  width: 160px;
                  height: 160px;
                  overflow: hidden;
                  display:block
                  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Syntax : overflow: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;
have a look in https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: I think you miss the point of the question as well `I want to display price tag in that css element but it is coming out of my card.`

Comment: oops sorry will  including a scroll helps ?